# Edit the Approval status Field on Vendor Bill-Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have a Workflow which defaults the Approval status on the VB record to "rejected" if the PO amt does not match the VB amt.

Now i shd allow one particular role alone to edit the approval status and save it to whatever he wants, How do i achieve this? I am using nlapisubmit to set the status.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write an User Event on your record and check the role of the user. One possible solution could be to disable the field for other roles.
Basically you can do something like this

On Load :

```
function clientPageInit(type){
    if(nlapiGetRole() != 'your_desird_roleId')  // check for the role
    nlapiSetFieldDisabled('yourstaus_field_internalid',true);  // disable the field edit for other roles
}
```

Or else you could throw an error on field change, if the role doesn't match with your desired role.

On Field Change :

```
function clientFieldChanged(type, name, linenum){

    if(name == 'yourstaus_field_internalid' && nlapiGetRole() == 'your_desird_roleId'){
    // allow to edit the status
    }else{
    throw nlapiCreateError('INVALID_ACCESS','You don't have access to change this field.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove the field from form on `beforeload` user event script for other roles as you have access to nlobjForm

```
//goes into before load function , additional condition, in case field is not there on the form,
if(nlapiGetRole() !== 'SPECIFIC_ROLE_ID' && form.getField('approvalstatus'))
   form.getField('approvalstatus').setDisplayType('hidden');
```

This ensures that the field is hidden to all users other than your role.

Additionally in your user event script before submit set the status to older status if role is other than desired one or throw an error, this would ensure if entry point is non-UI such as Script, CSV, Wenservices etc, the field value remains unchanged

```
//before submit to stop user from updating all together
if(nlapiGetRole !== 'SPECIFIC_ROLE_ID'){
  throw new nlapiCreateError('You are not authorised');
}

//before submit reset it back to old field value without showing any error
if(nlapiGetRole !== 'SPECIFIC_ROLE_ID'){
  nlapiSetFieldValue('approvalstatus, 'nlapiGetOldRecord().getFieldValue('approvalstatus'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So my code sets the status like this.    nlapiSubmitField('vendorbill', vendorBillID, 'approvalstatus','3');               // Get role
    var roleID = nlapiGetRole(); 
    // The role is  accountant
    if (roleID = 25) Should ideally set whatever he wants to.

Comment: ` nlapiSubmitField('vendorbill', vendorBillID, 'approvalstatus','3');`   `  Get role var roleID = nlapiGetRole();  `     `  if (roleID = 25) `  Role ID = 25 is for accountant he should alone be able to set the status whatever he wants to.

Comment: right, thats why I suggested if(nlapiGetRole() !== '25') {form.getField('status').setDisplayType('hidden');} in before load allowing only accountant to set what he/she wants to set from UI

Comment: Well this will be tricky. My code actually sets the approval status in the afterSubmit_changeBillStatus. Because the VB comes from a third party. So what i did was if(roleID == 25){
                         nlapiSetFieldValue('status', nlapiGetFieldValue('status')). Will this pick the new value which the accountant might enter while editing the bill? (Originally it will be defaulted to Rejected)

Comment: when VB comes from a third party what is the value of approval status (rejected?) ? and accountant sets the status from browser or third party API?

Comment: The VB and the PO comes from third party into NetSuite. When the PO amnt  and VB amt doestn matches the VB status is set to Rejected.  The accountant alone sholud be able to change the status of VB in Netsuite(UI) to whatever he wants which will be approved or pending approval ideally.

Comment: right, so use this //goes into before load function
if(nlapiGetRole() !== '25')
   form.getField('status').setDisplayType('hidden');

Comment: I tried that in Before load i get an error TypeError: Cannot call method "setDisplayType" of null

Comment: the fieldId got to be approvalstatus not approval . I have updated the answer, let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks, it was successful !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this second part would be a script. You already mentioned your first part is a work flow and this can be done in a workflows as well.

Just use set field display type - disabled/hidden in before record load with the condition role != the role you want to allow.

Based on your request this one action completes your needs. Same premise as the above answers but no need for a script